# OS X writing on NTFS filesystem: files disappeared after ls -l@

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, ntfs, terminal.app

I have an NTFS hard drive that I have written files to after following the [instructions here to allow for writing to NTFS](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-write-to-ntfs-drives-in-os-x-mavericks--cms-21434).  I noticed that if I write files to NTFS, after disconnecting the drive and reconnecting, the added files were grayed out.  As per [this discussion](http://macosx.com/threads/greyed-out-files-in-ntfs-mounted-hdd.317130/), they mentioned issues with extended attributes. This can be seen with `ls -l` with files having `@` symbol in the file permissions.

My problem is that after typing in `ls -l@` into the terminal 90% of the files in the folder disappeared. This includes files with `@` in the file permission along with a lot of files that did not contain the `@` in the file permissions.

**Even more curious:** After the files disappeared from the terminal, I could still go into the same folder in finder and open the disappeared files.  I thought I could resolve the issue by ejecting the hard drive and reconnecting. However, after reconnecting, the affected files do not appear in terminal or finder.

**My question:** what the heck does `ls -l@` do and why did it make my files disappear? Are the files really gone? Before I reconnected the hard drive, the files were not showing up in terminal but were showing up in finder.

Answer (score 0):

> **My question:** what the heck does `ls -l@` do and why did it make my files disappear? Are the files really gone? Before I reconnected the
>   hard drive, the files were not showing up in terminal but were showing
>   up in finder.

As clearly stated in the [man page for `ls`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html):

```
-@      Display extended attribute keys and sizes in long (-l) output.
```

All adding the `@` to an `ls -l` command would do is reveal extended attribute data connected to the file if it ever existed. The `ls` command would never write to a file/directory or modify data to a file/directory; it just reads data.

So in this case it seems like you are correlating one action (running `ls -l@`) with another result (files apparently disappearing) that has no connection to each other.

This could all be a simple—and classic—NTFS on Mac OS X headache issue; no matter what anyone says NTFS support in Mac OS X has never been great and has always cause people stress.